# Html5/javascript iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

in my html file i have an iframe whos src is a txt file, but when i try edit or move anything around in it through putting it in an array it says that it is readonly and i cannot seem to find anything that will make be able to write to it.

this is how its called in the html:

```
<iframe id="words" src="words.txt" width=10 height=10 style="display:none"></iframe>
```

and then in the javascript:

```
var w = document.getElementById("words");
var c = w.contentDocument.body.textContent;
var L = c.split("\n");
```

Comment: Are you working locally? (Is the scheme file://?)

Comment: instead of textContent, did you try innerText?

Comment: see also [document.documentElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.documentElement)